# Associated dimension of a detail disappears after reload / save

Tags: business-objects, webi

In BusinessObjects webi, I want to merge two variables, one from the universe, one from an excel file.

Query CC data (universe): Site

Query Site mapping table (excel file): Phenix Mapping Key (Entity Name)

If I merge the two dimensions in the report, it works.

However, if I merge the two dimensions using intermediate variables, the "associated dimension" of the detail got lost when saving, closing and reopening the document (or when refreshing it).

[image: Site (trim)]

[image: Phenix mapping key (trim)]

[image: Merged site name]

When creating the variable, it works, the values in the table appears:

[image: detail field with associated dimension]

However, after saving, closing and reopening, the "associated dimension" disappears and there is a #datasync error in the table (which is normal with no associated dimension):

[image: detail: the associated dimension has disappeared!]

Is it a problem in my code? SAP bug?

Version of SAP: SAP BusinessObjects BI Platform 4.2 Support Pack 3 Patch 2

Version of webi: 14.2.3.2220

Comment: I had exactly the same problem with 2 variables from 2 queries never understood why it happened. For some reason when I created a new report and tried to merge them again it worked... no idea why redoing the whole report fixed it. So I'm going with bug. Try to create a new report and just try to do the merge again as a test and see what happens.

Comment: I just created a new report with a few dimensions and the excel file. Same problem happened on the detail when saving / closing then reopening the report :(.